# How to toggle Image on click within Table?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-table

I want to display a table with a text and an image on each row. Clicking on the image should toggle the picture. The table is associated with an array of instances of a class, which has a boolean property for storing the state of the image.

[image]

Clicking seems to have no effect.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var items = [
        Item(id: 1, text: "Eins", isClicked: false),
        Item(id: 2, text: "Zwei", isClicked: true),
        Item(id: 3, text: "Drei", isClicked: false)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Table(items) { 
            TableColumn("Items") { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.text)
                    Button(action: {
                        item.isClicked.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: item.isClicked ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}

class Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var isClicked: Bool

    init(id: Int, text: String, isClicked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.isClicked = isClicked
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI is highly dependent on being able to identify when something has changed, it is mostly done via `Hashable`, `Identifiable` and `Equatable` but reference types require a little more work.

For a `class` to  work it must be an `ObservableObject` or an `Observable`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

The most compatible solution is to use a `struct` instead of a `class`.

```
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var isClicked: Bool

    init(id: Int, text: String, isClicked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.isClicked = isClicked
    }
}
```

Then the `View` will just need a minor adjustment.

```
struct TwoWayTable: View {
    @State private var items = [
        Item(id: 1, text: "Eins", isClicked: false),
        Item(id: 2, text: "Zwei", isClicked: true),
        Item(id: 3, text: "Drei", isClicked: false)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        Table($items) { //Enable two-way communication
            TableColumn("Items") { $item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.text)
                    Button(action: {
                        $item.wrappedValue.isClicked.toggle() //Affect the wrapped value so State can trigger a redraw.
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: item.isClicked ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If targeting iOS-17, try this approach using the `Observation` framework. When the `item` is changed, the view will refresh due to the observation.

```
@Observable class Item: Identifiable {  // <--- here
....
}
```

EDIT-1

If you are targeting ios-16+, then you could use this approach using `ObservableObject`.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataModel = DataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Table($dataModel.items) {
            TableColumn("Items") { $item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item.text)
                    Button(action: {
                        item.isClicked.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: item.isClicked ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [
        Item(id: 1, text: "Eins", isClicked: false),
        Item(id: 2, text: "Zwei", isClicked: true),
        Item(id: 3, text: "Drei", isClicked: false)
    ]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var isClicked: Bool
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue here is that SwiftUI's `Table` does not directly support interactive elements like buttons within cells. You should use `List` instead, which is designed to handle user interaction with its elements.

Try this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var items = [
        Item(id: 1, text: "Eins", isClicked: false),
        Item(id: 2, text: "Zwei", isClicked: true),
        Item(id: 3, text: "Drei", isClicked: false)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item.text)
                Button(action: {
                    item.isClicked.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: item.isClicked ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

class Item: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var isClicked: Bool

    init(id: Int, text: String, isClicked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.isClicked = isClicked
    }
}
```